# win32 api update the progressbar to a method

Tags: c++, api, winapi, progress-bar

I have a method which is responsible of saving immes from memory to the harddrive and at the end will return a boolean value. now I have created a progress bar. but I really dont know how I can conenct the progress bar to this method in a way that as far as the method is saving the progress get updated and show the blue bar. here is my code :

```
switch(_formatIndex){                   
        case 0:

            save.saveImages(_MatVector,0, path);

            int pb_pos;pb_pos= SendMessage(_progressBar, PBM_GETPOS, 0, 0); 
            while(pb_pos<100){
                SendMessage(_progressBar, PBM_SETPOS, pb_pos, 0);
                pb_pos++;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            save.saveImages(_MatVector,1, path);                                                
            break;
        }
```

Comment: It's not enough to update the progress bar, you need to let the message loop run so that the bar can repaint itself. You can do that by breaking the work into a separate thread, or by breaking the saves into steps which can be called from a custom message or in an idle function. Unfortunately I can't post any details at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hAutoParent,IDC_PROGRESS1),PBM_SETRANGE,0, MAKELPARAM(0,10 ));
    SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hAutoParent,IDC_PROGRESS1),PBM_SETBARCOLOR,0,(LPARAM)colorResult3);
    SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hAutoParent,IDC_PROGRESS1),PBM_SETBKCOLOR,0,(LPARAM)colorResult2);
    SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hAutoParent,IDC_PROGRESS1),PBM_SETPOS,0,0);

int iProgressPosition=0;//Intially global variable

SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hAutoParent,IDC_PROGRESS1),PBM_SETPOS, iProgessPosition,0);
//incremented global varibale in loop is equal to 10(setrange 10)
iProgressPosition++;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? Posting only code is often not very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

You need to know how many files are being saved, and then increment the progress bar after each file is saved, not all at once.  For example:

```
SendMessage(_progressBar, PBM_SETRANGE32, 0, NumberOfFiles); 
SendMessage(_progressBar, PBM_SETSTEP, 1, 0); 
SendMessage(_progressBar, PBM_SETPOS, 0, 0); 

for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfFiles; ++i)
{
    ...
    save.saveImages(_MatVector, _formatIndex, path);
    SendMessage(_progressBar, PBM_STEPIT, 0, 0); 
    ...
}
```

Alternatively:

```
SendMessage(_progressBar, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, 100); 
SendMessage(_progressBar, PBM_SETPOS, 0, 0); 

for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfFiles; ++i)
{
    ...
    save.saveImages(_MatVector, _formatIndex, path);
    SendMessage(_progressBar, PBM_SETPOS, (i * 100) / NumberOfFiles, 0); 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Aaaand another one from Remy! Nice answer.